# Pyomo ValueError: PositiveReals is not a valid domain

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo, valueerror, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to solve a constraint mixed integer non linear optimization problem using PyOMO. Specifically, I'm trying to find gear diameters and tooth numbers such that two given gear ratios are met. I'm really quite cornfused about how to use `Set()` and `Var()`. I've been reading the documentation but its not super super clear about what a Set actually is! Is it an index that I can use to access similarly grouped parts of the problem? Here is my code: (Python 3.5)

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import numpy as np

# Define Forward and Reverse Gear Ratios

fwd_ratio = 4.3
rev_ratio = 9.1

D_guess = [4.5, 11.5, 6.0, 10.0, 4.5, 2.5, 2.25, 9.0]
N_guess = [18, 46, 24, 40, 18, 20, 18, 72]

idx = np.arange(0,8)

print(idx)

model = AbstractModel()

# Declare Model Sets??? I tried this as first argument to Var(), didn't work

#model.Didx = Set(D_guess)
#model.Nidx = Set(N_guess)

# Declare Model Variables

model.D = Var(D_guess, within='PositiveReals', bounds=(1.0,None))
model.N = Var(N_guess, within='PositiveInteger', bounds=(18,None))

# Declare Objective Functions

def obj_funcD(model):

    F1 = (model.D[1]/model.D[0])*(model.D[3]/model.D[2]) - fwd_ratio

    F2 = (model.D[1]/model.D[4])*(model.D[6]/model.D[5])*(model.D[7]/model.D[6]) - rev_ratio

    return F1 + F2

def obj_funcN(model):

    F1 = (model.N[1]/model.N[0])*(model.N[3]/model.N[2]) - fwd_ratio

    F2 = (model.N[1]/model.N[4])*(model.N[6]/model.N[5])*(model.N[7]/model.N[6]) - rev_ratio

    return F1 + F2

# Declare Constraint

def con_func1(model):

    return model.D[1]/model.D[0] == model.N[1]/model.N[0]

def con_func2(model):

    return model.D[3]/model.D[2] == model.N[3]/model.N[3]

def con_func3(model):

    return model.D[1]/model.D[4] == model.N[1]/model.N[4]

def con_func4(model):

    return model.D[6]/model.D[5] == model.N[6]/model.N[5]

def con_func5(model):

    return model.D[7]/model.D[6] == model.N[7]/model.N[6]

# Create Constraint List

model.c1 = Constraint(rule=con_func1)
model.c2 = Constraint(rule=con_func2)
model.c3 = Constraint(rule=con_func3)
model.c4 = Constraint(rule=con_func4)
model.c5 = Constraint(rule=con_func5)

# Create Objectives

model.obj1 = Objective(rule=obj_funcD,sense='minimize')
model.obj2 = Objective(rule=obj_funcN,sense='minimize')

# Solve the Problem?

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')

instance = model.create_instance()

results = opt.solve(instance)
```

This code gives the following error:

```
WARNING: Element 4.5 already exists in set D_index; no action taken.
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 920, in _initialize_component
ERROR: Constructing component 'D' from data=None failed:
    declaration.construct(data)
    ValueError: PositiveReals is not a valid domain. Variable domains must be an instance of one of (<class 'pyomo.core.base.set_types.RealSet' at 0x1004bee98>, <class 'pyomo.core.base.set_types.IntegerSet' at 0x1004f2558>, <class 'pyomo.core.base.set_types.BooleanSet' at 0x1004f28f8>), or an object that declares a method for bounds (like a Pyomo Set). Examples: NonNegativeReals, Integers, Binary
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/var.py", line 573, in construct
    component=None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/var.py", line 299, in __init__
    "Integers, Binary" % (domain, (RealSet, IntegerSet, BooleanSet)))
ValueError: PositiveReals is not a valid d
```

I've also tried using `RangeSet()` and passing the associated Set as the first argument of `Var()` but this doesn't do anything either! I known I'm missing something super obvious here but I've been staring at the screen for 4 hours now and I'm enlisting your help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `within='PositiveReals'` to `within=PositiveReals`, etc.

The `within` (or `domain`) keyword should be assigned one the of set domain objects that get imported from `pyomo.environ`. They should not be assigned strings.